# Can't find "key" attribute in model with CarrierWaveDirect gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog, carrierwave-direct

I've been trying to implement direct upload with AWS and CarrierWave direct. I'm following the documentation.
I have a model: AppNotice. It has a column called `image`.
However, it seems like even though my model has the code `mount_uploader :image, AppNoticesImageUploader`, it does not have the key attribute.
Here's my uploader `app_notices_image_uploader.rb`:

```rb
class AppNoticesImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader

  process optimize: [{ quality: 50, level: 7 }] # Função executada antes do upload
  process :pngquant, if: :is_png?
  def store_dir
    'uploads/app_notices'
  end
end
```

And my carriewrwave config file:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'carrierwave/storage/fog'

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  # config.asset_host = ENV['ASSET_HOST_UPLOAD']
  config.storage = :fog
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'
  config.fog_directory  = ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY'] # S3 bucket
  config.fog_attributes = { 'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=315576000' }
  config.fog_credentials = {
    region:                ENV['FOG_REGION'],
    provider:              ENV['FOG_PROVIDER'],
    aws_access_key_id:     ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
  config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
end
```

My upload form is pretty simple and it is on the same page of my  "normal" form for app notices:

```
<%= direct_upload_form_for @uploader do |fi| %>
  <%= fi.file_field :image, onchange: 'validateSize(this, 5)' %>
  <%= fi.submit %>
<% end %>
```

the `validateSize` function just validates if the image has less than 5MB.
The app notices form is under it, they don't have anything to do with each other.

Here's my `new` action on app_notices_controller:

```rb
def new
    @app_notice = AppNotice.new

    if params[:key].nil?
      @uploader = @app_notice.image
      @uploader.success_action_redirect = new_brand_app_notice_url(@brand)
    else
      ## these are the examples i've tried and none of them worked
      # @uploader.update_attribute(:image_key, params[:key]) << undefined method `update_attribute' for #<AppNoticesImageUploader:0x00005648f4ff6778>
      # @uploader.key = params[:key]  << this one does not change anything
      # @app_notice.image.key = params[:key] << this one does not change anything
      # @app_notice.update_attribute(:key, params[:key]) undefined method `key=' for #<AppNotice:0x00007f49fd0018f8>
      # @app_notice.assign_attributes(:image_key, params[:key]) << undefined method `reject' for :image_key:Symbol
      @uploader = @app_notice.image
      # @app_notice.update_attribute(:image_key, params[:key]) # null value in column "description" violates not-null constraint
#  DETAIL:  Failing row contains (573, a92a2c73-0aa5-4695-8946-d56b65553d0b/yamper.png, null, f, null, 2021-12-15 12:53:43.965459, 2021-12-15 12:53:43.965459, null, null, null, null).

    end
  end
```

It is said that CarrierWaveDIrect adds the key attribute automatically and I can't get to it. So there should be and attribute `key` in the AppNotice model, but there isn't.

My model:

```rb
class AppNotice < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, AppNoticesImageUploader
  validate :validate_image_size, if: 'image.present?'

  private
    def validate_image_size
      image = MiniMagick::Image.open(image_url)

      if image[:height] > 750
        errors.add :image, 'A altura da imagem deve ser no máximo 750px.'
      end

      if image[:width] > 750
        errors.add :image, 'A largura da imagem deve ser no máximo 750px.'
      end
    rescue StandardError
      errors.add(:base, 'Erro ao salvar a imagem')
    end
end
```

The only question I found about this was [No update_attribute method on carrier wave direct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17620853/no-update-attribute-method-on-carrier-wave-direct) and none of the solutions worked for me.